# Data reduction for a data collected from micro controller?

Tags: compression, signal-processing, data-conversion

I have been given a project where I have to

- collect data
- reduce its size and
- send the data via bluetooth to some
  other storage.

At first I thought it is simple data compression and used zlib and did a program.

After showing it to my mentor he said that he doesn't need a compression algo; he wants to reduce the number of data sets it takes to represent the input wave.

For example: if a sinosudal wave is represented by some 100 points he wants to represent it in 80 points.

Is there any algorithm or function that can help me?

A little data loss is permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology you are looking for is resampling.  You can resample data to a lower rate (thus less data) if the data is bandlimited or can be low-pass filtered to below half the new lower sample rate.

Note that Sinc (or windowed Sinc) interpolation can be used to resampled at arbitrary ratios of sample rates.